# Simple boolean indexing gives AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple DataFrame, AR,  with 83 columns and 1428 rows:

```
In [128]:

AR.index
Out[128]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...], dtype='int64')

In [129]:

AR.columns
Out[129]:
Index([u'ARKOD', u'ANSNR', u'PNR', u'NAMN', u'MEDB', u'LAEN', u'GATA', u'ORT1', u'ORT2', u'LAND', u'TFNA', u'TFNB', u'BEH_BEHAR', u'BEH_BEHS1', u'BEH_BEHS2', u'BEH_BEHKV', u'BEH_BEHAR2', u'BEH_BEHS1_2', u'BEH_BEHS2_2', u'BEH_BEHKV2', u'BEH_BEHAR3', u'BEH_BEHS1_3', u'BEH_BEHS2_3', u'BEH_BEHKV_3', u'BEH_BEHAR_4', u'BEH_BEHS1_4', u'BEH_BEHS2_4', u'BEH_BEHKV_4', u'BEH25', u'FILLER1', u'BEHFT', u'SLP_SPLAR', u'SLP_SLPP', u'MOTSV', u'FILLER2', u'ATG_ATG25', u'ATG_ATG9', u'ATG_ATGFT', u'ATG_ATGOB', u'ATG_ATGUT', u'ATG_ATGSI', u'ATG_ATGDI', u'ATG_ATGFO', u'ATG_ATGUG', u'ATG_ATGAL ', u'ATG_ATGUL1', u'ATG_ATGUL2', u'ATG_ATGUL3', u'ATG_ATGUL4', u'ATG_ATGUL5', u'ATG_ATGUL6', u'ATG_ATGUL7', u'ATG_ATGUL8', u'ATG_ATGUL9', u'ATG_ATGUL10', u'ATG_ATGUL11', u'ATG_ATGUL12', u'ATG_ATGFU1', u'ATG_ATGFU2', u'ATG_ATGFU3', u'ATG_ATGFU4', u'ATG_ATGB1', u'ATG_ATGB2', u'SLUMP', u'STAT_STATF', u'STAT_STATO', u'STAT_STATA', u'STAT_STATK', u'STAT_STATU', u'STAT_STATH', u'STAT_STATR', u'ANTAL', u'ANTBT', u'ANTSM', u'ANTAE', u'ANTFU', u'ANTZL', u'ANTYL', u'STATL', u'ATB', u'ANTB ', u'FILLER2'], dtype='object')
```

When I do for example:

```
In [121]:

AR[AR.ANSNR==10042]
```

I get

```
AssertionError: Cannot create BlockManager._ref_locs because block [IntBlock: [ANSNR, PNR, MEDB, SLUMP, ANTAL, ANTBT, ANTSM, ANTAE, ANTFU, ANTZL, ANTYL, ATB], 12 x 1, dtype: int64] with duplicate items [Index([u'ARKOD', u'ANSNR', u'PNR', u'NAMN', u'MEDB', u'LAEN', u'GATA', u'ORT1', u'ORT2', u'LAND', u'TFNA', u'TFNB', u'BEH_BEHAR', u'BEH_BEHS1', u'BEH_BEHS2', u'BEH_BEHKV', u'BEH_BEHAR2', u'BEH_BEHS1_2', u'BEH_BEHS2_2', u'BEH_BEHKV2', u'BEH_BEHAR3', u'BEH_BEHS1_3', u'BEH_BEHS2_3', u'BEH_BEHKV_3', u'BEH_BEHAR_4', u'BEH_BEHS1_4', u'BEH_BEHS2_4', u'BEH_BEHKV_4', u'BEH25', u'FILLER1', u'BEHFT', u'SLP_SPLAR', u'SLP_SLPP', u'MOTSV', u'FILLER2', u'ATG_ATG25', u'ATG_ATG9', u'ATG_ATGFT', u'ATG_ATGOB', u'ATG_ATGUT', u'ATG_ATGSI', u'ATG_ATGDI', u'ATG_ATGFO', u'ATG_ATGUG', u'ATG_ATGAL ', u'ATG_ATGUL1', u'ATG_ATGUL2', u'ATG_ATGUL3', u'ATG_ATGUL4', u'ATG_ATGUL5', u'ATG_ATGUL6', u'ATG_ATGUL7', u'ATG_ATGUL8', u'ATG_ATGUL9', u'ATG_ATGUL10', u'ATG_ATGUL11', u'ATG_ATGUL12', u'ATG_ATGFU1', u'ATG_ATGFU2', u'ATG_ATGFU3', u'ATG_ATGFU4', u'ATG_ATGB1', u'ATG_ATGB2', u'SLUMP', u'STAT_STATF', u'STAT_STATO', u'STAT_STATA', u'STAT_STATK', u'STAT_STATU', u'STAT_STATH', u'STAT_STATR', u'ANTAL', u'ANTBT', u'ANTSM', u'ANTAE', u'ANTFU', u'ANTZL', u'ANTYL', u'STATL', u'ATB', u'ANTB ', u'FILLER2'], dtype='object')] does not have _ref_locs set
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Edit: sorry, here is the Pandas version:

```
in [136]:

pd.__version__
Out[136]:
'0.13.1'
```

Jeff's question:

```
In [139]:

AR.index.is_unique 
Out[139]:
True

In [140]:

AR.columns.is_unique
Out[140]:
False
```

Is is the last one making problems?

Comment: what version pandas,numpy,python; this looks like an older error

Comment: pls show ``AR.index.is_unique`` and ``AR.columns.is_unique``

Comment: AHH, that was the problem, Jeff. There where TWO columns named "FILLER2". I renamed one and now it works!

Comment: What is the proper etiquette now, should I delete this question?

Comment: it's fine to leave the question